# Передача в функцию по значению

Tags: c#

Есть код

```
...
private static void InitSequence(int[] sequence)
    {
        for (var i = sequence1.Length; i > 0; --i)
            sequence[i - 1] = i;
    }
...
public static void Main()
    {
        var count = int.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
        int [] sequence = new int[count];
        InitSequence(sequence);
}
```

Почему при передаче массива в функцию его значение в Main меняется, ведь передается он по значению, а не по ссылке. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, объекты ссылочного типа передаются именно в виде ссылки на объект, а не в виде содержимого объекта. И вот эту ссылку вы в функции поменять не можете, а то, что лежит по ссылке - поменять можете.

Comment: Не могли вы бы пояснить что значит "И вот эту ссылку вы поменять не можете"?

Comment: @Vantoto Если передать ссылку на объект по ссылке (с модификатором `out`), то можно и саму ссылку на объект внутри функции изменить, чтобы она указывала на другой объект.